# Is this Markov chain? If not, how can we transform it to Markov chain?

Tags: probability, distributions, markov-process

Consider a process $\{ X_n, n= 0,1,...\},$ which takes on values 0,1 or 2. Suppose $$P\{X_{n+1}=j| X_n=i, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},...,X_0= i_0 \} = \begin{cases} P^{\rm{I}}_{ij}, \text{when n} \ \text{is even,}\\P^{\rm{II}}_{ij}, \text{when n} \ \text{is odd}\end{cases}$$

Where $\sum_{j=0}^2 P^{\rm{I}}_{ij}= \sum_{j=0}^2 P^{\rm{II}}_{ij}= 1, i = 0,1,2. $ Is $\{ X_n,n \geqslant{ 0}\}$ a Markov chain ?

If not, then show how, by enlarging the state space, we may transform it to Markov chain?

Author answered this question as follows:

Let the state space be $S = \{0, 1, 2, \overline{0}, \overline{1}, \overline{2} \},$ where state $i(\overline{i})$ signifies that the present value is i and present day is even (odd).

Would any member of 'Cross validated' stack exchange elaborate this answer further?

Comment: Wait, is this process deterministic or am I missing something? Markov is more for probabilistic processes

Comment: The fact that the probabilities depend on the current iteration means it's not a markov chain (it has time inhomogeneity). Can you think of some Markovian way to record whether an iteration is even or odd?

Comment: @JohnMadden - you can have a time-inhomogenous Markov chain... see for example this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/168398/time-inhomogeneous-markov-chains which also answers the OP, albeit in the comments.